# GPG encryption is slow on macOS 11.5.2 after PKSIGN step

Tags: macos, gnupg, gpg-agent

For some reason GPG appears to take a long time, 2-3 seconds, when encrypting anything. This makes it especially hard to use with git since commits are slow and rebases are glacial.

```
$ time (date | gpg -bsau KEY_ID)
...
0.01s user 0.02s system 0% cpu 2.801 total
```

I'm using GPGSuite on macOS 11.5.2:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0
$ gpg --version | head -n1
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.27
```

I have disabled the retrieval of keys from a keyserver, per [this support thread](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/nightly/56-macgpg2-gpg-is-very-slow):

[image]

I don't have many keys in my keyring:

```
$ gpg --list-keys | grep -E '^(pub|sub)' | wc -l
      21
```

And the slowdown appears to be after the `PKSIGN` step and before the `byte(s) skipped` step:

```
$ date | gpg --debug-level 9 -bsau KEY_ID
...
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.1: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.1: underflow: A->FILTER (8192 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: buffer size: 8192; still buffered: 0 => space for 8192 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.0: underflow: eof (pending eof)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.1: A->FILTER() returned rc=-1 (EOF), read 0 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-2.1: pop in underflow (nothing buffered, got EOF)
gpg: DBG: iobuf chain: 2.0 '?' filter_eof=0 start=0 len=0
gpg: DBG: get_keygrip for public key
gpg: DBG: keygrip= XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
gpg: DBG: chan_4 -> RESET
gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_4 -> SIGKEY XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_4 -> SETKEYDESC Please+enter+the+passphrase+to+unlock+the+OpenPGP+secret+key:...
gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_4 -> SETHASH 8 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_4 -> PKSIGN

[--------> DELAY IS HERE <-----------]

gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- [ XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX ...(273 byte(s) skipped) ]
gpg: DBG: chan_4 <- OK
gpg: DBG: build_packet() type=2
gpg: DBG: iobuf-4.0: close '?'
gpg: DBG: free_packet() type=2
gpg: DBG: armor-filter: control: 4
gpg: DBG: armor-filter: control: 5
gpg: DBG: iobuf-3.1: close 'armor_filter'
gpg: DBG: armor-filter: control: 2
```

There's nothing special about my key other than it has a picture:

```
pub   rsa2048 2015-08-18 [SC]
      KEY_ID
uid           [ultimate] a paid nerd <nerd@example.com>
uid           [ultimate] [jpeg image of size 10830]
uid           [ultimate] keybase.io/apaidnerd <nerd@keybase.io>
uid           [ultimate] a paid nerd <nerd@example2.com>
sub   rsa2048 2015-08-18 [E]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed question. I have been wondering about the same thing on my M1 and often end up developing via ssh on my linux box due to the slowness. 

I ran your commands and am able to reproduce the same slowdown at PKSIGN.

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA I forgot that I asked this. I deleted my keychain and recreated it and I haven't had problems since. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exact cause, but a solution: Deleting my `.gnupg` directory fixed this.

I suspect that my `.gnupg` directory is now 15+ years old and probably has some old keys or legacy data in there. So I exported the keys I cared about, moved the directory out of the way, re-imported everything, and now everything is fast.

Comment: I'm going to try this when I have a second and will report back, thanks for your answer + response!

Comment: I was _finally_ able to test this on my machine (macbook m1) and no dice. Thanks for your answer and response, regardless. Signing git commits take between three and five seconds for me right now on 2.3.2